# What should I do if I'm getting no answers even after making a bounty?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounties

If I post a bounty and it expires without getting any answers, is there anything else I can do to get my question answered?

Comment: I have a 50-rep bounty on an Arqade question, yet it's only received about 20 more views since then :(

Comment: @DominatorX Can't get on Arqade on school computers :c Yeah, I assume that feels pretty disappointing. Sometimes people just don't know, I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could put in another bounty. That will give you some extra advertisement time, which will lead to more visibility and possibly answers. Note that the bounty will increase in value every time you place a new one.

Another thing you can do is review your question:

- Is it clear enough?
- Is it too broad to be answered reasonably? Narrowing it down might help.
- Can I show some effort that may help others to answer your question?
- Is it a fit for the site you are asking it on?
- Ask on the site's meta how your question can be improved.
- You can get extra exposure by sharing your question using social media.

In the end, this may not be the site where you will find an answer. Sometimes the tag is a niche tag. Sometimes the question just isn't answerable. You might need to go elsewhere to get an answer.

Comment: Bear in mind that the more bounties placed on a question, the higher the cost of each bounty.

Comment: Gah, I was hoping there would be another way. Thank you for the help.